# How to plot counts stackbar in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, frequency

Dataset contains "two friends" and coded "interaction" (all factors). I want to plot the frequency of type of interactions between two friends using a stacked bar. I tried the following code.

```
Friend1 <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
Friend2 <- c("1","1","2","2","1","1","2","2","1","1","2","2","1","1","2","2")
Interaction <- c("O","X","D","D","D","X","X","D/R","O","X","D","D","D","X","X","D/R")

df <- data.frame(Friend1, Friend2, Interaction)
df$Friend1 <- as.factor(as.character(df$Friend1))
df$Friend2 <- as.factor(as.character(df$Friend2))
df$Interaction <- as.factor(as.character(df$Interaction))

ggplot(df, aes(fill=Interaction, y=count(Interaction), x=Friend2)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", color = "white") + theme_classic() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1)) +   theme(strip.background = element_blank()) + facet_grid(.~Friend1)

Erorr: Error in UseMethod("count") : 
  no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "character"
```

How do I "count" these factors to visualize frequency of interactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `dplyr::count` expects a dataframe as its first argument and returns a dataframe. However, there is no reason to compute the counts as `geom_bar` will do that by default, i.e. get rid of `y=...` and `stat="identity"`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = Interaction, x = Friend2)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", color = "white") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1)
  ) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Friend1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative visualization using facets per "friends" column may make your counts clearer than a standard stacked bar:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, fill = Interaction)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, color = "white", size = 1, alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), size = 7,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), color = "white",
            fontface = 2) +
  facet_grid(Friend1 ~ Friend2, switch = "both") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  labs(x = "Friend1", y = "Friend2") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "gray90", fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]